# How to get the first row in a bs4 findall result using python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

MY CODE    IS GIVEN BELOW

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get(
    "https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=metadata_created+desc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# value = soup.find_all(class_='new-results')

for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'dataset-heading'}):
    print(hit.text)
```

MY RESULTS in several rows eg.

Culverts

Iowa Geographic Map Server

Potential Vorticity based parameterization for specification of Upper troposphere/lower stratosphere ozone in atmospheric models

A demonstration of the uncertainty in predicting the estrogenic activity of individual chemicals and mixtures from an in vitro estrogen receptor transcriptional activation assay (T47D-KBluc) to the in vivo uterotrophic assay using oral exposure

data for MRPAT simulation

Waterline ATS BG disinfection data

Computer Code for Industrial Wireless Measurement Analysis and Scenario Generation

MY QUESTION :

How can i get only the first row  eg. in this case  'Culverts'

Or how to get the first row from the bs4 findall results  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified little bit in your code.

```
import requests
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get(
    "https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=&sort=metadata_created+desc")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
# value = soup.find_all(class_='new-results')
#for hit in soup.find(attrs={'class': 'dataset-heading'}).text:
a = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'dataset-heading'}).text
print a
```

As @Sid said, use **find** to get only the first element. No need to use for loop and findall.

Comment: Works ! Thanks @Vekatesh_CTA

Answer (score 0):

try `soup.find` instead of `soup.findAll`.

This will only return the first result.